# Qual a diferença entre essas duas declarações?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Estava a ler alguns tutoriais e documentações e me deparei com duas formas diferentes de declarar o `RequestContext`:

```
RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
requestContext.execute(/*coisas*/);
```

e

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute(/*coisas*/);
```

O que eu quero saber é se existe alguma diferença entre essas duas, se sim, quais? Quando eu devo usar cada uma delas?

Comment: Na primeira versão, você guarda a instância na variável `requestContext`. Na segunda, se precisar dela de novo vai precisar chamar `getCurrentInstance` outra vez.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No primeiro exemplo, você está pegando a instância da classe `RequestContext` e inserindo em uma variável "local" (`RequestContext requestContext`) em que a sua manutenção altera o estado da classe "Singleton" (pelo que parece).

Já o segundo exemplo (`RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute(/*coisas*/);`) você estaria pegando a instância da própria classe e a alterando, então se necessitar dela em algum tratamento local, ao fazer `RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();` a instância já estará com o `.execute()` ativo.

Observe os códigos:

**Classe Principal.java**

```
private static Singleton singleton;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Estou alterando a própria classe Singleton;
    Singleton.getSingleton().setAtivo(false);
    System.out.println(Singleton.getSingleton().isAtivo());//Imprime false

    //Aqui a variável singleton está com a instância modificada da classe Singleton;
    singleton = Singleton.getSingleton();
    singleton.setAtivo(true);
    System.out.println(singleton.isAtivo());//Imprime true

    //O que acontece já que a variável singleton e a própria instância Singleton estão compartilhando informação;
    Singleton.getSingleton().setAtivo(false);
    System.out.println(singleton.isAtivo());//Imprime false
    //Ou até:
    singleton.setAtivo(true);
    System.out.println(Singleton.getSingleton().isAtivo());//Imprime true
    //Imprime true pois como a classe Singleton foi instanciada uma única vez (no próprio construtor da classe), as informações acabam compartilhadas; 


}
```

**Classe Singleton.java**

```
    private boolean ativo;

    private static Singleton retorno = new Singleton();

    private Singleton(){
        this.setAtivo(false);
    }

    public static Singleton getSingleton(){
        return retorno;
    }

    public boolean isAtivo() {
        return ativo;
    }

    public void setAtivo(boolean ativo) {
        this.ativo = ativo;
    }
```

Obs.: Utilizei o padrão Singleton pois foi o que a classe RequestContext me parecia ser.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, quando atribuo à uma variável eu vou usar a mesma `getCurrentInstance` e quando chamo direto eu crio uma nova `getCurrentInstance`?

Comment: O `getCurrentInstance()` é usado para retornar a única instância que existe daquela classe.Por exemplo, se você tentar executar `RequestContext rc = new RequestContext();`, não será possível pois o construtor está `private` dentro da própria classe, ou seja, somente ela, a classe em questão, tem acesso. O que o `getCurrentInstance()` faz é retornar uma sessão da classe `RequestContext` que já esteja na memória, e que seja única (por ser `static`), que foi criada quando o "servidor", no caso, foi criado.

Comment: Então o que você está fazendo quando chama ela para dentro de uma outra variável, é somente criando uma nova referencia para a instância que está dentro da classe `RequestContext`, e alterar a nova variável ou o próprio `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();` não fará diferença.